# Show Möbius-Transformation with certain properties

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I've got to show that such transformation $f$ with mapping points $f(0) = -1$, $f(i) = 0$, $f(+\infty) = 1$ has properties $f(D_1) = D_2$ where $D_1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \vert \quad \text{Im$(z)$}\geq 0\}$ and $D_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C}\vert \quad |z|\leq 1\}$

I figured $f = \dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$ includes all the points of the sought transformation. My problem is at the root of showing that property. My idea is to substitute $z = a+i\,b$ and then calculate the absolute value of $f(z)$. Afterwards taking the limit of $|(f(z))|$ where $a \to\infty$ respectively $b\to\infty$ both with maximal value $1$. I have done these calculations before but it seems like a lot of paperwork for such a task, regardless of the fact this is legitimate. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Use the fact that mobius transformation takes generalised circles to generalised circles and circles are determined by 3 points on them.

Comment: But as far as I see that transformation maps a rectangle with area on the upper health plane to a circle with radius $1$.

Comment: @Leon $f(z) := \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ has $f(i) = 0$??

Comment: My apologies, it is $\dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$

Comment: $D_1$ may be a limiting case of "rectangles," but from the POV of the Riemann sphere it (with the point-at-infinity) is a disk bounded by the real axis (plus infinity, which is a generalized circle). So Ajay's comment applies. Even without that viewpoint, the calculations should be pretty straightforward, not "a lot of paperwork." For instance, plugging in $z=\infty$ *immediately* yields $f(\infty)=1$, and $|f(z)|^2\le1$ follows from $z=a+bi$ and $b>0$ by clearing denominators to write it as $a^2+(b-1)^2\le a^2+(b+1)^2$, then subtracting to one side and factoring with difference-of-squares...